# Adding external jar in a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a maven project (I use the jersey template, since I'll be creating an API) and would like to add an external jar file. I tried to follow this [reference here](http://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/)

[image]

I'm using Eclipse Mars in Windows environment. I added the following depedency to my pom.xml file

[image]

Now, when I try to use the jar file in my application, why is that I can't access it? The classes in the jar file couldn't be resolved.

[image]

Comment: Never use system scope dependency. Upload this jar to your corporate repository manager and that's it.

Comment: +1 on the previous comment. And I feel it needs to be said a second time: don't use the `system` scope, use a repository manager.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use file system based repos for this kind of thing.

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
    <id>local-files</id>
    <name>local-files</name>
    <url>file://c:\test\filerepo</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then you can install files into the file repo...

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=onebusaway-gtfs-1.3.3 -DgroupId=org.onebusaway.gtfs -DartifactId=onebusaway-gtfs-1.3.3 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=c:\test\filerepo
```

Just include the above `<repoisitory>` entry into any pom you want to have access to the file repo.  For example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>some-artifact</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
       <repository>
        <id>local-files</id>
        <name>local-files</name>
        <url>file://c:\test\filerepo</url>
       </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.onebusaway.gtfs</groupId>
      <artifactId>org-onebusaway-gtfs-1.3.3</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```